# How can I set Windows paths properly to be recognized easly by CMake?

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmake

I'm on Windows 10 64 bit verson 1703. Recently I wanted to build Tesseract-OCR library from scratch for learning purposes. Along the way I had to build several other libraries put them into a single folder and named it "myLibrary" (C:/myLibrary) and set it in the Windows path variable. Even though the other libraries built successful I still had difficulties with CMake finding the libraries even when 'C:/myLibrary' is in the path. Is it that every time a new library is added a specific project's CMakeLists.txt file has to be modified to see the library? or can it be assumed that CMake has features to find the libraries as long they are in the path? Is it enough to just set 'C:/myLibrary' in the path or should I add the 'bin' and 'lib' folders of each compiled libraries for them to be found by CMake?

Comment: I don't think it has the smarts to dig into "bin" and "lib" folders, as not every project uses the same convention. You'll need to explicitly add these. In my opinion, if you are using the `PATH` variable for code libraries, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: fyi the `PATH` environment variable is for finding executable (exe, bat etc) not includes and libs.

Answer (score 2):

Windows PATH won't help you detect libraries in CMake. If that even works at all, it's not by design and probably very error prone. In CMake, the best way to add libraries via `LIST` manually. e.g.

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PRIVATE
    "${LIB_PATH}/foo.lib"
    "${LIB_PATH}/baz.lib"
    "${ANOTHER_LIB_PATH}/buzz.lib"
    ...
}
```

You can `GLOB` for libraries in a path as well, but this is not encouraged as you would need to rerun CMake manually to pick up any new library. `GLOB` can't detect new libraries on its own, but suppose you don't mind that:

```
file(GLOB LIBS "${LIB_PATH}/lib*.dll")
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PRIVATE ${LIBS})
```

Another important thing to remember is you shouldn't rely on system specified paths for CMake, you need to specify the location with `set` before `target_link_libraries` e.g.

```
set(LIB_PATH "C:/myLibrary")
```